# How to get the lowest FLAT RATE shipping cost in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, shipping-method

What I want is simple: I want to display the lowest flat rate shipping cost on a product page in WooCommerce so I can display: "We already deliver orders from € ...".

It doesn't matter what shipping zone of customer country is active... I just need the overall (static) lowest flat rate cost available.

So far I have this:

```
foreach ((array) $delivery_zones as $key => $delivery_zone ) {

    $shipping_costs = [];

    foreach ($delivery_zone['shipping_methods'] as $value) {
        $shipping_costs[] = $value->cost;
        break;
    }

    echo (min($shipping_costs));
}
```

But this still outputs ALL the flat rate costs f.i.: 1,99 3,99 5,99

How can I only display the lowest (in this case 1,99) rate?

Many tnx!

Comment: Can you tell us which hook do you use to edit the product page or provide us the screenshot which shows the current rates on the product page?

Comment: I don't use hooks in my case. I just created a small plugin to display various order info (like costs, delivery day, etc) to display on a product page. That answers your question? I hope you have the awnjser :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a simple mistake, please try this:

```
function get_lowest_shipping_flat_rate_1()
{
    $delivery_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones(); 

    //define the array outside of the loop
    $shipping_costs = [];
    $min_zone = "";

    //get all costs in a loop and store them in the array
    foreach ((array) $delivery_zones as $key => $the_zone ) {

    foreach ($the_zone['shipping_methods'] as $value) {
        $shipping_costs[] = $value->cost;
        if(min($shipping_costs) == $value->cost) $min_zone = $the_zone['zone_name'];
        }
    }

    $content = $min_zone . " - " . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . " " . min($shipping_costs);

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: This does indeed outputs only 1 value but its not the lowest. When I changed the 1,99 flat price to 11,99 it showed 11,99 and not the new lowest of 3,99. It looks like it always displays only the first string... Does that makes sense?

Comment: Well, I just tested the code again by creating a new cheaper flat rate and also changing the minimum flat rate (i mean two different tests), it is working fine for me..

Comment: I see... Well then this probably has to do something with the different shipping zones I use. Your code probably works fine within a single zone. Thanks for your work my friend :) To bad I can't use it. I have to search deeper.

Comment: I think this must work for you too, anyway I hope you can find a better solution. Have a good day.

Comment: I just tried your edited code (without the BREAK) but that code doesn't output anything so I again tried your first code (wanting to believe it should work) but again it doesn't. No matter I change shipping prices, the output price is always the exact same shipping rate. Could it be that the output is ordered by shipping rate NAME instead of the shipping rate cost?

Comment: Yes I think that's the clue.... When I give both shipping ZONES the SAME NAME your code (the one with BREAK) works... So maybe a simple change in the codes fixes this?

Comment: Can you try the updated code please? Copy and paste it to functions.php, then just write "echo get_lowest_shipping_flat_rate_1();" , Working in my test website: http://eyupgulsen.com/test/urun/sunglasses/

Comment: I'm going to solve it an other way but I would like to thank you for your help.